# Error consuming API endpoint using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I am using Guzzle to consume an API but for some reasons, I get this error:

> http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given.

I don't know what I might be doing wrong. This is my code:

```
$data = ["name" => "joe doe"];
$jsData = json_encode($data);

$headers =  [
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}"
];

$call = $this->client->post(env('URL'),[
    "headers" => $headers,
    'form_params' => $jsData
]);

$response = json_decode($call->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

---

**Edit**

```
$data = ["name" => "joe doe"];

$headers =  [
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}"
];

$call = $this->client->post(env('URL'),[
    "headers" => $headers,
    'form_params' => $$data
]);

$response = dd($call->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Client error: `POST http://localhost/send` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded", "u (truncated...)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing the error is that [`form_params`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) should be an `array` but you're running the array through `json_encode` which returns a string:

```
$data = ["name" => "joe doe"];
$jsData = json_encode($data);

// ...

    'form_params' => $jsonData
```

You should simply pass the data through as an array, without running it through `json_encode`:

```
$data = ["name" => "joe doe"];

// ...

$call = $this->client->post(env('URL'), [
    "headers" => $headers,
    'form_params' => $data
]);
```

Comment: I am now getting this error - Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: What do you see if you put `dd($call->getBody()->getContents());` before your `json_decode` line?

Comment: Same error - Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Can you update your question with what your code currently looks like after making those changes?

Comment: Can you add the full error to the question as well? Underneath the code block in the edit section.

Comment: I see, that error appears to be coming from the API you're consuming rather than the code you've posted in your question to handle it. It looks like the API is complaining about the data you're sending it. I would need to know more details about the API to help you further. I would recommend opening a new question though as it's getting to be a little beyond the scope of this one.